# Why do both sides of an equation equal to a constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

this is a very general question, and I might have missed out some conditions in order for the above statement in question to be true. If I have, please help me state these conditions, thank you.

It is often used in derivations in physics, when you have an equation, take for example in thermodynamics, we have the equation relating two systems:

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E_1}\right)_{V_{1}, N_{1}} = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E_2}\right)_{V_{2}, N_{2}}$$

The derivation goes on to state, since the two sides of the equation are equal, they must be equal to a constant, thus the constant, temperature $T$ is defined to be:

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E_i}\right)_{V_{i}, N_{i}} \equiv \frac{1}{T_i}$$

This kind of thinking is used as well in the derivation of Schrondinger's equation. Could anyone explain to me what the mathematical reason is? As well as any conditions I might have left out.

Comment: The essential idea boils down to this: the two sides of your equation are functions of different variables, i.e. you have something like $f(x)=g(y)$. This is only going to be true for any value of $x$ and $y$ if the functions $f$ and $g$ are both constant functions (and the same constant, of course, because of the $=$ sign).

Comment: I see, thus this statement will not be true if the functions share a same variable? because it no longer implies constant function with any value of variables?

Comment: @Tian:  that is correct.  You could have the case where you prove $f(x,y)=g(x,z)$ and conclude that $f$ does not depend on $y$ and $g$ does not depend on $z$, so $f(x,y)=g(x,z)=h(x)$ but that doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can I check: what do you mean by 'but that doesn't seem to happen.'?

Comment: It means that I can imagine it but didn't see it during my education.  I saw many cases where we had both functions be constant.